# Twin Strike and keywords from frost weapon and radiant weapon (and dual implement feat)

Tags: dnd-4e, keywords

I would like to know if when I'm dual wielding an frost weapon and a radiant weapon the keywords cold and radiant gets applied to both attacks, or say if you make the first attack with the frost weapon and the second with the radiant then only the first attack gains the keyword cold and the second the keyword radiant.

Also I would like to know something similar in when using the feat dual implement if you have an frost weapon and an radiant weapon do both the keywords cold and radiant gets applied to your implement attack or is it only the case if you for example use an frost weapon and an crusader weapon(converting only half damage to radiant)

Comment: Hey Kriek looks like you might need to merge accounts, this is showing up under a new one. http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts has instructions on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

**You only apply the abilities of the weapon making the attack...**

In both the implement and weapon example that you gave you would only be able to apply the damage type from the weapon used in the attack  The only exception to this is that weapons that have properties that are work simply when equipped or held would still apply to an attack made with another weapon. For example, the vanguard weapon adds a bonus to charge attacks as a property when the weapon is equipped. I can wield a vanguard weapon in my off-hand and attack with a radiant blade by charging and still get the benefits from vanguard weapon on my attack.

Also, the feat you mention, dual implement spellcaster, only works with *arcane* attacks and only adds the off-hand implement's enhancement bonus to the damage rolls of the attack made by the main hand implement. You can use it with arcane *weapon* attacks, but only if you can use both your weapons as implements. This mostly means heavy or light blades.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton added the bit about the feat from the comments, do you mean flag the comments?

Comment: Yep, but a comment to me works almost as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Although you might like to imagine visually that a warrior battles using both of his weapons, rules-wise each attack uses either one weapon or the other. Most attacks will just get the benefit(and damage type) of the weapon in your primary hand. You can tell which attacks use the other weapon because the power you use will specify 'off-hand'.

The same applies to implement attacks.